# Prove that $g^{-1}(0)$ is a $n$-dimensional manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Let $A\subset \mathbb R ^n$ be open and let $g:A\to \mathbb R ^p$ be a differentiable function such that $g'(x)$ has rank $p$ whenever $g(x)=0$. Then $g^{-1}(0)$ is an $(n-p)$-dimensional manifold.

This is Theorem 5-1 in Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" and the proof is: "It follows immediately from Theorem 2-13.[]"

Theorem 2-13 says practically that (under the same hypothesis) if $x\in A$, then there is an open set $U$ containing $x$, an open set $V\subset \mathbb R ^n$ and a diffeomorphism $h:U\to V$ such that $$g(h(x))=(x_1,...,x_p).$$

My bad, I can't see how does the theorem follow immediately from this. To prove that $g^{-1}(0)$ is a $(n-p)$ manifold, I should find open sets $U'$ with $x\in U'$, $V'$ and a diffeomorphism $h':U'\to V'$ such that $$h'(g^{-1}(0)\cap U')=V'\cap [\mathbb R ^{(n-p)}\times \{0\}],$$
where $0$ is the $\mathbb R ^p$'s zero. How do I construct $U'$, $V'$, $h'$ starting from the given $U,V,h$? The only ideas that come to my mind are silly things like $$f(x)=I(x)-(0,g\circ h(x)),$$
where $I$ is the identity and $0$ is the $n-p$ one.

I'm very unfamiliar with this stuff, so I'm probably missing some pedantic application of the definition, can you give me some hint?

Comment: I think the $h'$ in question is the $h^{-1}$ of theorem 2-13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming $n>p$) I think this statement is a version of the so called *regular value theorem*.

Here $0\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is the regular value and by Theorem 2-13 $g\circ h:U\to\mathbb{R}^p$ satisfies $g(h(x_1,\dots,x_n))=(x_1,\dots,x_p)$. Then, $(g\circ h)^{-1}(0)=h^{-1}\left(g^{-1}(0)\right)=\{(0,\dots,0,x_{p+1},\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ work as coordinates of an $(n-p)$-dimensional smooth manifold on $A$.